# Function for a function-based spatial index: if X not null and Y not null (can't contain spaces)

Tags: sql, oracle, function, indexing, decode

I want to create a [function-based spatial index](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-objects-function-based-indexes.htm#SPATL799) to speed up a spatial query.

```
create index workorder_idx on 
    workorder(mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null))
    indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
```

The **function/expression** in the *function-based spatial index* needs to be structured in a specific way so that a matching record can be stored in USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA.

> [2.8.2 COLUMN_NAME - USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/geometry-metadata-views.htm#SPATL545)
>
> The COLUMN_NAME column contains the name of the column of type SDO_GEOMETRY.
>
> The column name is stored in the spatial metadata views in all
> uppercase characters.
>
> The column name **cannot contain spaces** or mixed-case letters in a
> quoted string when inserted into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view, and it cannot be in a quoted string when used in a query (unless it is in all uppercase characters).

---

Since the column name **can't contain spaces**, that means my function/expression can't contain spaces either.

That's fine, except I want to handle cases where X or Y is null — I want to return null in that case, rather than have `mdsys.sdo_geometry()` error-out when there are nulls.

---

Normally, I'd handle this with a case statement:

```
case when x is not null and y is not null then
    mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null)
end
```

However, the case statement has spaces in it. So that won't work.

Instead, I want to do something like use the `decode()` function:

```
decode(x and y, not null, mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null))
```

But I don't think that's how the decode function works. And there are spaces in that expression anyway.

---

**Question:**

Is there a out-of-the-box function that can be used for this scenario that doesn't contain spaces?

- I would prefer to do this with an OOB Oracle function, rather than create a custom function, since I don't have CREATE FUNCTION privileges.
- The db version is Oracle 18c.

**Edit:**

It turns out that it's not necessary to add a record to ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA when using the function-based spatial index in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use decode if you chain them to check x followed by y.  Not sure it's much more classy but here you are...

```
CREATE TABLE t(
 x number,
 y number
);

insert into t values (1, 2);
insert into t values (null, 2);
insert into t values (1, null);
insert into t values (null, null);
insert into t values (5, 10);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geo_Ret RETURN varchar2 AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'use function';
END geo_Ret;
/

SELECT DECODE(DECODE(x,null,null,1)+DECODE(y,null,null,1),2,geo_ret) from t;
```

First decode checks x and returns 1 or null, second checks y and returns 1 or null, third adds the two together and returns the function output if they equal 2, else null.

Output:

```
use function
(null)
(null)
(null)
use function
```

Edit:
If you need the x and y values change the decode default output to x instead of 1 and y instead of 2, and change third decode to check for null rather than 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not classy, but using [NVL2()](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php) seems to work for this:

```
nvl2(x+y,
     mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null),
     null)
```

An explanation of parameters 1-3:

1. `[string1]` : Since `anything + null = null`, that means if either x or y are null, then the result will be null.
2. `[value_if_not_null]` : This is my SDO_GEOMETRY expression/parameter.
3. `[value_if_null]` : Else, null.

---

Here is a simple SQL example:

```
with cte as (
select    1 as x,    2 as y from dual
union all
select null as x, null as y from dual
)
select
    x,
    y,
    nvl2(x+y,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null),null) as shape
from
    cte

         X          Y  SHAPE                                                                           
---------- ----------  --------------------------------------------
         1          2  SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,26917,SDO_POINT_TYPE(1,2,NULL),NULL,NULL)                     
      null       null  null
                                                                                
2 rows selected.
```

---

USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values(
    'WORKORDER',
    'nvl2(x+y,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null),null)',
    sdo_dim_array(
        sdo_dim_element('X', 663795.93, 676674.94, 0.001),
        sdo_dim_element('Y', 4857659, 4879068.83, 0.001)), 26917);

1 row created.
```

---

Create function-based spatial index:

```
create index workorder_idx on 
    workorder(nvl2(x+y,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(x,y,null),null,null),null))
    indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;

Index created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

NVL2(X,NVL2(Y,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,26917,mdsys.sdo_point_type(X,Y,NULL),NULL,NULL),NULL),NULL) "NVL2 Logic"